# How to filter People Picker by wildcard in SharePoint?

Tags: powershell, people-picker

Here is the situation:

Some users have a real account and a ghost accounts/dummy accounts in same domain but with hyphen in the account name.

For example :

John Adams real account is domain\JA001 and his ghost account is domain\JA001-aa

So when we search in people picker by name it shows both accounts.

Question is how to exclude all users with *-aa to show in people picker?

Any help with PowerShell command will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the People Picker or People Search/User Profiles?

Comment: It is a People Picker control which searches AD for users

Comment: OK, I removed the User Profile tag that you set to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i ran from the command line to exclude the *-aa accounts and it worked for me:

stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter -pv "(!(sAMAccountName=*-aa))" -url https://MyWebApplication.com

Answer (score 0):

How would I do this if I wanted to filter out users from a specific sub-domain? I can use the same command as above I just am not sure what condition to check for?

I would use something like this:
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter -pv "(!(<>))" -url https://MyWebApplication.com

where <> needs to be that the userPrincipalName does not contain the sub-domain name.

Comment: Yes. That should work.

Comment: How would I set that condition though?

Comment: How about trying something like this :

Comment: stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter -pv "(!(userPrincipalName=*crescent.org))" -url https://MyWebApplication.com

Assuming crescent.org is the domain you want to exclude